Read XML from one file, and insert sections of it into another XML
I am trying to read some XML from details.xml, open company.xml and insert some nodes from details into company and then save the company.xml. Both of these XMLs are under C:\Temp.
All the details > properties nodes from details.xml will need to go into the second company node in company.xml.
company.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rootdir>
    <properties>
        <something></something>
        <company>1234</company>
        <company>{{details go here }}</company>
    </properties>
</rootdir>

details.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rootdir>
    <details>
        <properties>
            <companyname>Acme Inc</companyname>
            <address>100 Ocean Dr</address>
            <city>LA</city>
            <state>CA</state>
            <zip>90210</zip>
        </properties>
        <properties>
            <companytype>Engineering</companytype>
         </properties>
         <properties>
            <licenseno>2024-ABC123</licenseno>
        </properties>
    </details>
</rootdir>

The end result is going to look like this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rootdir>
    <properties>
        <something></something>
        <company>1234</company>
        <company>           
            <properties>
                <companyname>Acme Inc</companyname>
                <address>100 Ocean Dr</address>
                <city>LA</city>
                <state>CA</state>
                <zip>90210</zip>
            </properties>
            <properties>
                <companytype>Engineering</companytype>
            </properties>
            <properties>
                <licenseno>2024-ABC123</licenseno>
            </properties>
        </company>
    </properties>
</rootdir>

This is what I have so far :
 public static void TestMerge()
 {
      string destinationXml = "C:\\temp\\company.xml";
      string sourceXml = "C:\\temp\\details.xml";

      XElement xFileRoot = XElement.Load(destinationXml);
      XElement xFileChild = XElement.Load(sourceXml);

      var querySource = xFileChild.Element("details");
      var queryDestination = xFileRoot.Element("properties");
      Console.WriteLine(queryDestination); 
  }

I have 2  nodes, so not sure how to put the details in the second one.
Any suggestions?

This question is similar to: How to insert an XML File into Another XML File at Specific Node C#. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks, it doesn't look like a solution was accepted. Looking into it.

Is your xml model firm? <company>1234</company> next to <company><properties> is odd

Also the nested <properties> seen multiple times with different definitions.

I stand by xmlserialization, see some of my answers using it: here and here. In your case, the xml structure does not make this easy

Alternatively LinqToXml should make this easy, see XDocument and XElement classes

yes, certain nodes are repated. I have no control over fixing them.

Please try the following solution leveraging LINQ to XML.
It is heavily commented, so it is easy to understand what it is doing.
c#
void Main()
{
    const string companyXml = @"C:\Temp\company.xml";
    const string destinationXml = @"C:\Temp\company_new.xml";
    const string detailsXml = @"C:\Temp\details.xml";
    
    // load both XML files
    XDocument xdocCompany = XDocument.Load(companyXml);
    XDocument xdocDetails = XDocument.Load(detailsXml);
    
    // find a correct company
    XElement company = xdocCompany.Descendants("company")
        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Value == "{{details go here }}");
    
    // get properties fragment
    IEnumerable<XElement> properties = xdocDetails.Descendants("properties");

    if (company != null && properties.Any())
    {
        // replace textual node with the properties fragment
        company.ReplaceAll(properties);

       // save final XML document
       xdocCompany.Save(destinationXml);
    }
}


Awesome. Thank you!

how would I go about changing from c.Value == {{details go here }} to using the 2nd company node? The actual xml does not have a place holder for details go here.

FirstOrDefault() and then using Add() solved it for me. Thanks
